# Как сделать, чтобы при заходе на gif картинку, выполнялся скрипт PHP?

Tags: php

Реализована такая возможность на сайте 2ip.ru Шпион. Ты кидаешь картинку пользователю, он заходит на неё, и все данные (IP и прочее) отсылаются владельцу.

Comment: скорее всего  наоборот:
просто картинка отдается через php, а тем временем и собирается информация вся

Comment: В адресной строке, путь к картинке.

Comment: Ну да, может это реализовано из PHP, но как сделать маскировку под картинку?

Comment: nety nikakoy maskirovki. Header otdaetsa gif

Comment: я пробовал сделать header с gif, но при заходе на gif, ничего не происходило

Comment: zahodit na  php ynuzhno - on otdaet put kartinky

Comment: При заходе на пхп, картинку вывело. Но в адресной строке - всё та же PHP. Возникает вопрос, как тогда реализовали это 2ip?

Comment: mozno ssilku gde eto?

Comment: Инвайт нужен, но на их форуме тоже задаются вопросом.
http://2ip.ru/forum/thread.php?postid=7851

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кладете в каталог три файла - `.htaccess`, `spy.php`, `spy.gif`(рисунок)

```
-- .htaccess --

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ip\.gif$ spy.php
```

---

```
-- spy.php --

<?
if ($f = fopen('ip.txt', 'a+')) {
  fwrite($f, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n");
  fclose($f);
  }
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
readfile('spy.gif');
?>
```

Ссылку даете на `ip.gif`, в файле `ip.txt` появляется последний IP. Соответственно, в `spy.php` пишете что угодно, но не забывайте последние 2 строки.

Comment: ахах))) пока ковырялся тут уже все готово)))

Answer (score 1):

```
//htaccess
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.gif$ spy.php/$1 [NC]

//PHP
<?php

if(isset($_GET['spy']))
{
    //все данные (IP и прочее) отсылаются владельцу
}
else
{
    //делаем картинку заманилку на GD PHP)))
}

?>
//HTML
<a href="http://axample.com/image.gif"><img src="http://axample.com/image.gif" /></a>

//P.S.
Суть я думаю ясна) Знания + Фантазия = Результат)
```